# InvBoxCox defaulting to FALSE in R library "forecast"

Tags: r, transformation, inverse

I am using the following script:

```
lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(coronaCa,lower=0)
InvBoxCox(coronaCa, lambda, biasadj = FALSE, fvar = NULL)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning message:
In InvBoxCox(pred$pred, lambda, biasadj, pred$se^2) :
biasadj information not found, defaulting to FALSE.
```

Can someone help? I would be greatful. Thanks

Comment: that is not an error but just a warning. It tells you that the function didn't find any information in the variable biasadj and is hence using the default. But since you also past the default value to this variable I see no problem hier.

Comment: Thanks Bertil, but biasadj = FALSE it should not default. I absolutely need the back-transformed  values. The data on the transformed scale has no meaning.